# Pycharm: Is there a way to save a break point state and debug going forward?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

When debugging a code in Pycharm is there a way to save current state before proceeding forward? That way I do not have to re-process everything that was already debugged if there is a bug downstream.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can create a temporary [debug template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-saving-temporary-run-debug-configurations.html) to make it easier to get back to the point you're at, it is not possible to save the entire state of a running debug session and modify code downstream. My only suggestion would be to run a new instance of your script and keep the debug open for the current session as it is.

Comment: Thanks ... I am too used to the convenience of notebooks (am a data scientist) ... but when I take code out of there and am turning it into "real code" .. I miss the ability to just work on a cell -- without rerunning everything upstream if I something bugs out.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment to the "correct" answer, it sound like what you really want is the interactiveness, which you can easily have in PyCharm in multiple ways.

**Through debugger:**
One way is to set a break point, and then start executing code in the console from this state. You can execute a large selection of code or just one line at the time.

**Without debugger:**
Another option is to just use the Python console to execute code interactively. Also here you can execute a large selection of code or one line at a time.